# UILabel adding double quotes between number and percent sign

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building an iOS app (XCode 9.3.1, iOS 11.3, Swift 3.3), with a UITableView and UITableViewCell, in which I add some UILabel.

If there's a number followed by a space and a percent sign in the label text (e.g. 25 %), it automatically adds a double quote between the number and the percent sign. If there is no space between, I don't have this issue. Same if the space is preceded by letters instead of a number.

```
self.amorce.frame = CGRect(x: labelX, y: currentY, width: labelWidth, height: 0)
self.amorce.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.amorce.frame.width
self.amorce.text = "25% 25 % 32 % 32% bleh% bleh %"
self.amorce.sizeToFit()
```

Result is :

[image]

Anyone ever had this issue or knows how to fix this?

**Edit** :

If I don't change the font and use the default one, I don't have this problem. Could it be a bug with my font? It's weird because if it's not a number (e.g. twenty %), even though there's a space between, there's no problem.

Comment: Does it help if you escape the % sign, like so: `self.amorce.text = "25% 25 \% 32 % 32% bleh% bleh %"`?

Comment: @Frederik I tried but you can't in Swift, \% is invalid you have to double escape it, and it outputs "25 \%", which is not what I want!

Comment: Can you add the code where you insert the double quotes?

Comment: @CodeDifferent This is the problem, I don't insert any double quote as you can see in my code snippet, but it outputs double quote in the label text, which is the problem!